# The image of a square after linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For this question consider: $T : R
^2 → R
^2$ given by reflection across the line $y = 3x$ and $S : R
^2 → R
^2$
given by rotation anti-clockwise about the origin by an angle of $π/
2$
.

(a) Draw the image of the square with corners at $(0, 0),(1, 0),(0, 1),(1, 1)$ under the map $T$.

(b) Draw the image of the square with corners at $(0, 0),(1, 0),(0, 1),(1, 1)$ under the map $S$.

(c) Draw the image of the square with corners at $(0, 0),(1, 0),(0, 1),(1, 1)$under the map $S ◦ T$.

Hey all, for a question like this, is there a simple method to calculate the new corners of the square (after transformation)? I know that this could be done with observation but is there a more mathematical approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: One can write down explicit matrix representations $[S], [T]$, resp., of the transformations $S, T$. If we do this w.r.t. to the standard basis $((1, 0), (0, 1))$, then the images of the four corners are $(0, 0)$, the first column of $[S]$, $[T]$, or $[S][T]$, the second column of the appropriate matrix, and (by linearity) the sum of those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can calculate matrices for the transformations: $${\bf R} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\-\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{rr}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$$For the reflection, we can construct it using knowledge of it's [canonical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_basis) like this, first we conclude that the vectors fulfulling $y=3x$ are $[1,3]^T$ and that they are left unaltered but all vectors orthogonal to it are mirrored (multiplied by $-1$): $${\bf M} = {\bf V}{\bf PV}^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}-3&1\\1&3\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{rr}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{rr}-3&1\\1&3\end{array}\right]^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}-0.8&0.6\\0.6&0.8\end{array}\right]$$

Now just put the corners into column-vectors and multiply with the matrices from the left. For convenience you can just put the columns after one another in a bigger matrix $\bf C = [c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4]$ and the output of $\bf MC$ and $\bf RC$ will be the 4 corners in the same order. For the composition in c) you can just stack the matrix multiplications in the same order as the composition.

Comment: **EDIT** I found some sneky errors. It should be more correct now.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

By transforming the basis elements, we obtain the transformation matrix

Matrix of T= $\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{-4}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \\
    \frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{5} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Matrix 0f S = $\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Now multiply each vector with the corresponding matrix and obtain the new coordinates